# Для публикации поста на страницу сначала надо сходить в отладчик

Tags: facebook-api

Попытаюсь объяснить проблему. Есть приложение в фейсбуке, которое публикует ссылки на страницу. Все налажено, права даны, через `fb:pages` подтверждена "дружба" сайта и страницы.

Запускаю приложение (или тоже самое в эксплорере), получаю ответ

> (#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture,
>   name, thumbnail or description params.

Иду в отладчик. Отладчик говорит, что информации про страницу нет. Говорю -  получи. Получает. Возвращаюсь в эксплорер, повторяю запрос - всё отлично.

Почему он решает, что я не владелец сайта, не прочитав код страницы на сайте? И как бы это исправить?

Comment: Такая же хрень... Нигде ничего. Написал на Facebook. Неужели только через Business Manager?

Comment: я им написал еще тогда. Надеялся, что поправят, видимо, до сих пор нет. Эффект наблюдается и просто в эксплорере

Comment: @sergvm я вот так решил проблему - заставляю мордокнигу обновить кэш https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100574/is-there-an-api-to-force-facebook-to-scrape-a-page-again